# my cat wants to play

Tags: cats

but doesn't find anything interesting to her. I have bought many new toys, recycled old toys that she used to love, wands, da bird, mice, catnip, laser and more. I am talking about playing with us, not solitary play. she is constantly "talking" a very, very lot, and will roll on her back, asking for play, but then won't play. she is 4. she loves being brushed and will ask for it and get it, 4 or 5 times a day.
any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Does [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/my-cat-will-only-play-with-silicone-earplugs-how-do-i-fix-that) answer yours? Sounds like a similar question.

Comment: Hi J Lynne! Please view the question I have duplicated yours to, it should have the answers you are looking for :)